# Object vs Subject?

Tags: subjects, objects

Consider the following sentence:

> "Even during the simple occurrence of **him and me** standing next to each other makes me notice that he's taller than me."

Is ***him and me*** correct? Should it be ***he and I***?

Comment: That's of form "Even during X makes me notice Y", which does not make sense.  Leave out *during*.  As Barrie notes in his answer, the sentence is unlikely to occur in normal speech of native speakers.  That's because it's clumsy and roundabout.  One might instead say "Just standing next to him makes me notice he's taller than me", or "When I meet him, I notice he's taller than me", or a thousand other variations better than the original.

Comment: Leave out _during_. Then it's fine. _During_ starts a prepositional phrase, which can't be a subject. But its object can.

Answer (score 6):

The choice is not between *him and me* and *he and I*, but between *him and me* and *his and my*. But in any case, this sounds like a fabricated sentence unlikely to occur in the normal speech of native speakers. Apart from anything else, there's something wrong with the syntax. It looks as if you want *the simple occurrence* to be the subject of the sentence. If so, you can't have *during* there.

Comment: Completely agree on all counts.  (Conjunctions of pronouns have become an anarchic area of grammar.)

Comment: I went around and around on this.  It appears to me that it is the word "occurrence" which favors using the possessive. Because "standing" is the occurrence, and "us" cannot modify "standing."   But if it were couched as a "sight" then it would be ok. "She could not stand the sight of us standing together" because in that case "we" are the sight, and "standing together" modifies "us". I am not entirely sure about this though. Thoughts?

Comment: @Tolerance72: ‘She could not stand the sight of us standing together’ better illustrates the question the OP may be asking. I don’t think many would argue for ‘we standing together’. ‘Us standing together’ foregrounds the fact that it’s ‘us’ doing it. ‘Our standing together would foreground the act of standing together itself.