# Is it "George and I" or "George and me"?

Tags: grammar, subjects, objects, indirect-objects

Recently, at McCain's funeral Obama said:

> "After all, what better way to have the last laugh than to make **George and I** say nice things about him to a national audience."

Is it "George and I" or "George and me"?

Comment: Is it "me" or "I", if you eliminate George?

Comment: (This was an unusual error on the part of Obama.  However, in this context using "me" sounds a bit too informal, and using "myself" sounds a bit stuffy.)

Comment: Related: 1. [“Who wants ice-cream?” — Should I say “(not) I” or “(not) me”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/who-wants-ice-cream-should-i-say-not-i-or-not-me) 2. [“It is me” vs. “It is I”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30336/it-is-me-vs-it-is-i) and 3. [Which one is correct to say: “It's me” or “It's I”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10643/which-one-is-correct-to-say-its-me-or-its-i)

Comment: Also related: 1. [Should it be “you and I” or “you and me” in the song “We are the world”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/403163/should-it-be-you-and-i-or-you-and-me-in-the-song-we-are-the-world) 2. [Object vs Subject?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74128/object-vs-subject) and [Which is correct, “you and I” or “you and me”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/which-is-correct-you-and-i-or-you-and-me)

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to figure this out is, as Michael said in a comment to another answer, to drop the first part of the combination:

Would it be

> After all, what better way to have the last laugh than to make **I** say nice things about him to a national audience.

Or

> After all, what better way to have the last laugh than to make **me** say nice things about him to a national audience.

This makes it obvious that Obama made a mistake. And that may seem strange, since he is not only a native speaker of English, but he is quite an accomplished user of the language, and an example to many.

So why would he make such a mistake? I think what's going on is a phenomenon called [hypercorrection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection). For quite a while, speakers used to use *me* in sentences like the one in this question, even when it should be *I*, resulting in sentences like

> *George and me are off to the super market.
>   *Paul and me failed our exam.

Teachers and other people who insisted that *I* should be used in these sentences seem to have managed to convince people that the use of *me* is *always* wrong, resulting in people overcorrecting and using **he gave John an I a present*.

Comment: Hasn't this question been asked a zillion times already on this site. Do we want to spread good answers among several duplicate questions, or keep them together under one roof?

Answer (score 1):

Needn't go into nominative/accusative case analysis - the simple test shown is the right one: "Make George say nice things - make me say nice things; make George and me say nice things."

Could've been the modern, and even uglier, "Make George and myself say nice things."

Omarosa had this same issue on a recorded TV program recently.  I think the network should have given her an opportunity to correct this, as young people have fewer examples of correct usage.

Answer (score 0):

It will be *George and me*.

It would be George and I if it was- *George and I do this*.

But in this case it is- *Someone/something make George and me to do this*.

Comment: Simple method to decide: take out 'George and' - is it 'make me say nice things' or 'make I say nice things'?

Comment: You cannot say "make George and me **TO** do this" because the *to* is ungrammatical there. Also, please do not use code markup on ELU. That isn't computer code: it's text used as a mention. Those are best set in italic.